# 'jshint':'Don't make functions within a loop'

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jshint

Any other way of using function inside a loop?

I get a jshint error saying 'Don't make functions within a loop'.
          `

```
       //inside loop 

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',function(){

        if (this.getAnimation() !== null) {
        this.setAnimation(null);
```

Comment: You can define the function outside the loop. You usually only need a single function, not a separate one for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 myFunction = function(){};
   //loop starts

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',this.myFunction);
```